# Cannot establish connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis, iis-7, remote-connection

I am trying to access SQL DB that is located on my computer from an application that is located on a server (has IIS7).
I set the ConnectionString in the WebConfig with the IP of my computer and I always get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I wanted to enable remote connections as it was mentioned in the error. These are the things that I tried in order to make it work:

1. Made sure that "Allow remote connections" to this server is checked in the properties window of my server
2. Enabled TCP/IP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager
3. Right clicking on the TCP/IP and in "Properties" set the port to 1433 and removed the "0" in the Dynamic Ports
4. Created a new rule in the Windows Firewall to allow the connection from port 1433
5. Added sqlservr.exe from the MSSQL/Binn folder to "Allow a program through Windows Firewall"
6. Restarted the service

None of it helped. What else can I do?

**EDIT:**
Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="someName" connectionString="Database=someDB;Server=<my computer's IP>;User=userName;Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you post your connection string.

Comment: Have you restarted the SQL Server Process, after you changed the TCP/IP settings ?

Comment: Have you tried ping, telnet, SSMS?

Comment: Only the service... I don't see it in the processes

Comment: Are you sure there's not another firewall in the way? Is port 1433 allowed through the firewall(s)?

Comment: Do you have mixed mode authorization enabled in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I am showing SQL Express setting this should be same in standard and other versions.
check this and follow the first link for connection specification and testing for this problem.

[image]

Check these links for checking error exists regarding this particular topic and fixing this:
[Resolving “A network-related or instance-specific error"](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/)
[SQLAuthority- could not open connection](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)